# How to make FoldListIndexed ie FoldList with an index or iterator?

Tags: list-manipulation, function-construction, functional-style

Is there a functional or inbuilt way to add an index to `FoldList`?

i.e.:

```
FoldListIndex[f,x,{a,b,...}]
```

gives

```
{x,f[x,a,1],f[f[x,a,1],b,2],...}
```

My current method with a loop is quite unsatisfactory

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
foldIndexedList = Module[{i = 1, f = #}, FoldList[f[##, i++] &, ##2]] &;
foldIndexedList[f, x, {a, b, c, d}]
```

> {x, f[x, a, 1], f[f[x, a, 1], b, 2], f[f[f[x, a, 1], b, 2], c, 3], 
>    f[f[f[f[x, a, 1], b, 2], c, 3], d, 4]}

```
foldIndexedList2 =  Module[{f = #}, 
    FoldList[f[#, ## & @@ #2] &, #2, MapIndexed[{#, #2[[1]]} &]@#3]] &;
foldIndexedList2[f, x, {a, b, c, d}]
```

> {x, f[x, a, 1], f[f[x, a, 1], b, 2], f[f[f[x, a, 1], b, 2], c, 3], 
>    f[f[f[f[x, a, 1], b, 2], c, 3], d, 4]}

Comment: Thanks rafalc and kglr for the answers. 

I selected kglr as it resulted in a faster function for my specific implementation and it worked with foldIndexedList[f,{a,b,c,d}] as well

Comment: @user62657, thank you for the accept; and welcome to mma.se.

Answer (score 4):

You can try

```
FoldListIndexed[f_, x_, lst_] := 
    FoldList[
        Function[{a, b}, f[a, Sequence @@ b]],
        x,
        Transpose[{lst, Range @ Length @ lst}]
    ]
```

and then

```
In[4]:= FoldListIndexed[f, x, {a, b, c, d}]

Out[4]= {x, f[x, a, 1], f[f[x, a, 1], b, 2], 
    f[f[f[x, a, 1], b, 2], c, 3], f[f[f[f[x, a, 1], b, 2], c, 3], d, 4]}
```

Comment: Nice solution, but I would rather avoid using `Block`, especially for functions living in ``Global` ``. Imagine that `g` has been defined globally, and is called by `f` - then this code will break it in a very non-obvious way. I would rather use a pure function for `g`, and `With` instead of `Block`.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin thank you, I have edited my answer following your suggestions (got rid of Block entirely - I think the code is still readable even without the helper variable)